# How insert Floating Action Button inside extends fragment

Tags: java, android

```
public class frag_aide extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton fab_profile,fab_face,fab_twi ;
    Animation FabOpen,FabClose,FabClockwise,FabantiClockwise;

    boolean isOpen=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fab_plus =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(fab_plus);
        fab_nav=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(fab_nav);
        fab_fb =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(fab_fb);
        fab_twitte=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(fab_twitte);

        FabOpen= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_open);
        FabClose= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
        FabClockwise= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotation_clock);
        FabantiClockwise= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotation_anticlock);

        fab_twi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isOpen) {
                    fab_profile.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_face.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_twi.startAnimation(FabantiClockwise);
                    fab_profile.setClickable(false);
                    fab_face.setClickable(false);
                    isOpen = false;
                } else {
                    fab_profile.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_face.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_twi.startAnimation(FabClockwise);
                    fab_profile.setClickable(true);
                    fab_face.setClickable(true);
                    isOpen = true;
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have an issue in `setContentView`, `findViewById`, and `getApplicationContext`. How do I insert the floating action button in fragment using 'extends Fragment'?

Comment: You can not use `setContentView` in `Fragment`. You should use `onCreateView()` instead.

Comment: i change it but i sill have problem with "findViewById / getApplicationContext" 
how can i fix this 
Cause i want insert the floating in page of ResideMenu

Comment: Post your updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fab_twitte=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(fab_twitte);
```

you setting fab_twitte here ,but adding a listener with `fab_twi.setOnClickListener` where did `fab_twi` should be fab_twitte.

the main problem is the way you are creating the views for the fragment. I sure you read about the life cycle of fragments where the fragments are attach and detach from their corresponding activity.

Do not inflate your layout in onCreate, use onViewCreated becuase this is the equivalent for the activity onCreate. Use the onCreate in fragments to initialize stuff not bind your layout.

Here is a  more detail explanation.Android fragments have their own life cycle very similar to an android activity. This section briefs different stages of its life cycle.
onAttach()The fragment instance is associated with an activity instance.The fragment and the activity is not fully initialized. Typically you get in this method a reference to the activity which uses the fragment for further initialization work.

onCreate() The system calls this method when creating the fragment. You should initialize essential components of the fragment that you want to retain when the fragment is paused or stopped, then resumed.

onCreateView() The system calls this callback when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View component from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

onActivityCreated()The onActivityCreated() is called after the onCreateView() method when the host activity is created. Activity and fragment instance have been created as well as the view hierarchy of the activity. At this point, view can be accessed with the findViewById() method. example. In this method you can instantiate objects which require a Context object

onStart()The onStart() method is called once the fragment gets visible.

onResume()Fragment becomes active.

onPause() The system calls this method as the first indication that the user is leaving the fragment. This is usually where you should commit any changes that should be persisted beyond the current user session.

onStop()Fragment going to be stopped by calling onStop()

onDestroyView()Fragment view will destroy after call this method

onDestroy()onDestroy() called to do final clean up of the fragment's state but Not guaranteed to be called by the Android platform.

```
so just change from onCreate to onViewCreated ,plus fix the changes i stated in the aforementioned.
```

**** also do not use getApplicationContext, use getActivity() this returns the context for the current activity it is attached to.In simple terms getApplicationContext returns the context for the entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside of). Use this instead of the current Activity context if you need a context tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, not just the current Activity. So no do not use it.

Comment: i all ready change it
but no things happend
i need to know how adding in fragment cause i'm beginner in Android

Comment: answer was edited please re-read a more detail explanation is provided sir.

Comment: yes i still find errors
This line :
 
        fab_plus =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(fab_plus);
        fab_nav=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(fab_nav);
        fab_fb =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(fab_fb);
        fab_twitte=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(fab_twitte);
And show me this :
findViewById  (int)
in View cannot be applied
to (android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton)

Comment: please describe the error , and update your initial question with your correction so further assistance can be given.

Comment: Caspain ! plz can you halp me in this 
the app is working
but whene i click a button she crashed

Comment: provide some info please. ill see where we can go from there.

Comment: i all ready posted new answer . look up and tell me what wrong in the code 
And thanx Bro

Comment: use getBaseContext() instead.

Comment: where i should use getBaseContext() ?
cause i'm new in android i don't know so match about Fragment

Comment: remember what i said earlier, do not inflate your layouts in onCreate, use onCreateView. And do not use getApplicationContext, use getActivity() in it's place.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class frag_aide extends Fragment {

        FloatingActionButton fab_nav,fab_fb,fab_twitte, fab_plus ;
        Animation FabOpen,FabClose,FabClockwise,FabantiClockwise;

        boolean isOpen=false;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            onCreateView(R.layout.aide);
            fab_plus = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(fab_plus);
            fab_nav = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(fab_nav);
            fab_fb = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(fab_fb);
            fab_twitte = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(fab_twitte);

            FabOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
            FabClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
            FabClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotation_clock);
            FabantiClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotation_anticlock);

            fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (isOpen) {
                        fab_nav.startAnimation(FabClose);
                        fab_fb.startAnimation(FabClose);
                        fab_twitte.startAnimation(FabClose);
                        fab_plus.startAnimation(FabantiClockwise);
                        fab_nav.setClickable(false);
                        fab_fb.setClickable(false);
                        fab_twitte.setClickable(false);
                        isOpen = false;
                    } else {
                        fab_nav.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                        fab_fb.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                        fab_twitte.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                        fab_plus.startAnimation(FabClockwise);
                        fab_twitte.setClickable(true);
                        fab_nav.setClickable(true);
                        fab_fb.setClickable(true);
                        isOpen = true;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: You are using fragment so you can not bind your view inside onCreate. Do it in onCreateView and inflate your layout first (Do some research about fragment lifecycle)

Comment: Please edit your question to update or provide additional information. Please don't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //For you, you have nothing to do here
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aide, container, false);

         fab_plus = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(fab_plus);
         fab_nav = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(fab_nav);
         fab_fb = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(fab_fb);
         fab_twitte = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(fab_twitte);

        return rootView;
    }

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        FabOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
        FabClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
        FabClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotation_clock);
        FabantiClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotation_anticlock);

        fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isOpen) {
                    fab_nav.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_fb.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_twitte.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_plus.startAnimation(FabantiClockwise);
                    fab_nav.setClickable(false);
                    fab_fb.setClickable(false);
                    fab_twitte.setClickable(false);
                    isOpen = false;
                } else {
                    fab_nav.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_fb.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_twitte.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_plus.startAnimation(FabClockwise);
                    fab_twitte.setClickable(true);
                    fab_nav.setClickable(true);
                    fab_fb.setClickable(true);
                    isOpen = true;
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: this answer is misleading , you did not answer the question. Plus you code is error prone,getApplicationContext() should be getActivity()

Comment: I did not pay attention to this, use getContext() instead of it

Comment: There is no a question at all, i just pointed that binding views in fragment

Comment: Look bro . the project is create ResideMenu and in each page there is funtion and one of Pages must have button action . But when this class was empty the app was Running and work

Comment: i try this.getActivity() And she work but i have some other probleme

Answer (score 0):

```
public class frag_aide extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton fab_nav, fab_fb, fab_twitte, fab_plus;
    Animation FabOpen, FabClose, FabClockwise, FabantiClockwise;

    boolean isOpen = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //For you, you have nothing to do here
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aide, container, false);

        fab_plus = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(fab_plus);
        fab_nav = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(fab_nav);
        fab_fb = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(fab_fb);
        fab_twitte = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(fab_twitte);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        FabOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fab_open);
        FabClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fab_close);
        FabClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotation_clock);
        FabantiClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotation_anticlock);
        fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isOpen) {
                    fab_nav.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_fb.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_twitte.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_plus.startAnimation(FabantiClockwise);
                    fab_nav.setClickable(false);
                    fab_fb.setClickable(false);
                    fab_twitte.setClickable(false);
                    isOpen = false;
                } else {
                    fab_nav.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_fb.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_twitte.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_plus.startAnimation(FabClockwise);
                    fab_twitte.setClickable(true);
                    fab_nav.setClickable(true);
                    fab_fb.setClickable(true);
                    isOpen = true;
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to update or provide additional information. Please don't post it as an answer.

Comment: @xlm Please don't edit answers that aren't answers. You've cleared my not-an-answer flags.