# Check if i'm inside or outside radius of circle

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, geometry

** I have a Map and I add some localization with Marker and radius
- I want some code to let me know if I'm in the radius or not**

*this is my code:*

```
public class FirstFragment extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout1);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.gps:
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
    //Enable the GPS
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }}
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // first place where i want Marker
        // first place where i want Radius
        LatLng COLLEGE = new LatLng(36.848339, 10.268338);
        Marker college = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(COLLEGE));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(COLLEGE));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(COLLEGE));
    //add the circle
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
     circleOptions.center(COLLEGE);
        circleOptions.radius(1000);//add the radius
        mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

        // first place where i want Marker
        // first place where i want Radius

        LatLng MAR = new LatLng(36.806495, 10.181532);
        Marker mar = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MAR));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(MAR));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(MAI));
      //add the circle
        CircleOptions circle = new CircleOptions();
        circle.center(MAR);
      //add the radius
        circle.radius(1000);
        mMap.addCircle(circle);
    }}
```

always when i search about do something when I'm inside radius of circle
i can understand the effect of this code and i don't know where can insert it in my `FirstFragment`

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
    float [] distance = new float[];
    Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(),
    location.getLongitude(),-6.x,106.xx,distance);

       if (distance[0] < 50)
       {
          Intent i = new Intent(student_activity.this,indoor.class);
          student_activity.this,startActivity(i);
       }
  }
```

Comment: You can use getActivity() instead of this.

Comment: "this" in your code represent context . The code you have provided is in Activity . So in your case the context is the activity itself. As fragment is a part of activity you can use getActivity()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Activity** you have to use `this` to accses to *context*, *cursor*..etc

but in **fragment** we use `getActivity()` instead.

Comment: Bro
the app working but whene i run it and click a button she stoped

Comment: whene i run the in my app
she open and i see a MAP but whene i click a button she stoped
i don't know how i show you the probleme

Comment: please try to ask new question, or edit your current question if it's the same problem

Comment: Ibrahim plz can u help me ?
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577541/how-insert-floating-action-button-inside-extends-fragment/42577633?noredirect=1#comment72418326_42577633)
the code is in this link

Comment: you should read about [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: If you have PDF or Site can help me give bro
And thax

Answer (score 1):

Just use `getActivity()` instead of `this`

Comment: whene i run the in my app she open and i see a MAP but whene i click a button she stoped i don't know how i show you the probleme

Answer (score 1):

Use getActivity()

```
      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling // ActivityCompat#requestPermissions // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding // public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, // int[] grantResults) // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details. return; } mgoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
```

Comment: whene i run the in my app she open and i see a MAP but whene i click a button she stoped i don't know how i show you the probleme

Answer (score 1):

Use getActivity() and ContextCompact for fragment:

Replace this:

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

With:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Comment: whene i run the in my app she open and i see a MAP but whene i click a button she stoped i don't know how i show you the probleme